# How to count rows group wise in mysql with java and hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, count

I have a database "javachat" with one table and two columns.
one of these columns is called "nickname" and the second one is "post" so it looks like:

```
nick1 post1
nick2 post2
nick1 post3
nick2 post4
```

and now: i need to count how many posts every nickname wrote (i have to count how many nicknames i have in database and how many times they appear). its important that i know the nickname too because i want to create chart with nickname and number of posts.

maybe this question is pretty stupid but i couldnt find anything by searching. the code i wrote for now is just to connect to the database and i have no idea what to do now.

```
private ???????? downStats() {
        try{
        Session sess = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();


        tx = null;
        sess.disconnect();

    }
              catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        textArea.append("Sorry - could connect to the database!");

    }
    }
```

any ideas? thank you in advance for any hints.

Comment: Have you created entity classes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is `Table`

```
select name, count(post) from Table group by name;
```

This is how I got your question, and if I got wrongly, then please update your question with expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following Query

```
SELECT COLUMN-NAME-OF-NICKNAMES, COUNT(1) FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY COLUMN-NAME-OF-NICKNAMES
```

This will return each nick name with number of posts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the associated SQL query you'll have to use:

```
"SELECT nickname, count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY nickname"
```

Now, you need to use Hibernate for this.

```
sess.createCriteria(MyTable.class)       
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                   .add(Projections.groupProperty("nickname"))
                   .add(Projections.count("someColumn"))           
    ).list();
```

Take a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection).

Comment: groupProperty - i understand that is a name of the column but count - someColumn? i dont get it.

Comment: I'm sorry, you should replace 'someColumn' with 'posts' or '1' to return the count of posts, or the count of rows retrieved. Either way will return the right value.